# ORA-00904 invalid identifier for nested select

Tags: oracle, where-clause, identifier

I have been stuck on this error for 2 hours.

I have nested select to get the first value.

```
select tbl.table_name,
       (select distinct(FirstItem)
       from
           (select first_value(column_name) over (order by timestamp asc rows unbounded predecing) as FirstItem
           from log_table_b l
           where tbl.assignment_no = l.rpt_no)
       ) as "USERNAME",
from prod_table tbl;
```

It returns this error:

```
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00904: "TBL"."ASSIGNMENT_NO": invalid identifier
```

I have tried many things, none of them seems to be helping me.

Comment: You can not use the outer table in inner select.

Comment: @Mureinik for the inner query, it is returning multiple rows.. it is throwing this error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` that's why I wrote this `select distinct(FirstItem)...` query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the parent table in inner sub query. Here how you could achieve this :

```
with tmp_table as 
(
    select rpt_no, first_value(column_name) over (order by timestamp asc rows unbounded predecing) as FirstItem
    from log_table_b l
) select distinct tbl.table_name, firstItem
from prod_table tbl
join tmpTable on tmp_table.rpt_no = tbl.assignment_no;
```

You might want to find a more descriptive name to *tmp_table*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can only pass a reference from an outer query down to the next subquery level.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
select tbl.table_name,
       (select min(column_name) keep (dense_rank first order by tstamp asc)
        from   log_table_b l
        where  tbl.assignment_no = l.rpt_no
       ) as "USERNAME"
from   prod_table tbl;

select tbl.table_name,
       l.username
from   prod_table tbl
       inner join (select rpt_no,
                          min(column_name) keep (dense_rank first order by tstamp asc) username
                   from   log_table_b l
                   group by rpt_no)
         on (tbl.assignment_no = l.rpt_no);
```

N.B. untested